# line 61: Mismatched input 'strategy.entry' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Tags: pine-script

So, I have been googling and searching here for answers as well, but I just can't figure out where the mistake here is...
Any kind of lead is highly appreciated!

PS: the line 61 is actually the line where "if testPeriod()" is, if it helps.

```
if testPeriod()
   strategy.entry("long", true, when = entry_long, comment="YOUR_COMMENT")
   strategy.exit("long", when=exit_long, stop=long_stop_level, limit=long_take_level, comment="YOUR_COMMENT")
   strategy.close("long", when=exit_long, comment = "YOUR_COMMENT")
   
   strategy.entry("short", false, when = entry_short, comment="YOUR_COMMENT")
   strategy.exit("short", when=exit_short, stop=short_stop_level, limit=short_take_level, comment = "YOUR_COMMENT")
   strategy.close("short", when=exit_short, comment = "YOUR_COMMENT")
```